# MAC XAMPP with MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm learning Web Programming through XAMPP with MYSQL Workbench. 
I'm trying to connect localhost:3306 with Workbench, but keeps failing.

[image: I made a new account on localhost/phpmyadmin]

I made a new account on localhost/phpmyadmin. 
`User name: phpadmin, pw: phpadmin`

And i'm trying to connect this user to Workbench, but keeps failing.

[image]

I entered Username and Password, and tried `Test connection`. 
But it keeps showing me Filed to connecto MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user phpadmin
[image]

I tried re-downloading XAMPP and Workbench, but it didn't work.
And I also tried to connect Workbench with root user. It seemed work, but it couldn't fetch data from localhost. 
[image]

So i tried to upgrade mysql, but it didn't work neither.

```
mysql -u root -p
\Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

What should I do?
Please Please Please help me...

Comment: The problem is that this is not a programming error. If you provide the correct connection parameters, user name and password, then mysql workbench will connect to mysql. A typical cause for this error is if you have multiple mysql instances running and your phpmyadmin connects to one, and you are trying to connect via workbench to another. Xampp uses mariadb and not mysql. The two products are highly compatible, but the list of the incompatibilities are over 15 pages long. Mysql workbench was designed by mysql to work with mysql and it **will** encounter problems uf you use it with mariadb.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! As you commented, I have multiple mysql apps in my MAC. I tried to delete instances through 'SYSTEM PREFERENCES'. But it didn't work well. Do you think that it's the problem of using mariadb with mysql workbench?

Comment: Nope, authentication-wise it should work. But you are probably mixing the various instances up.

Comment: Then, what i should do is deleting all instances of mysql except XAMPP mariadb instance! Did i understand correctly?

Comment: Yep, you should only keep one instance, unless you really need multiple different ones. But more importantly, you have to pay attention which one you want to connect.

Comment: I deleted all the other Mysql instances. I failed to connect user "phpadmin" to Workbench, but i could connect root to Workbench.

Comment: The database connected with root user seemed work, but it is not able to fetch tables from localhost.